# How to filter and save each variable on matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a data (matrix) with 3 columns : `DATA=[ID , DATE, Value]`
I want to filter my data by `ID` for example `DATAid1= DATA` where `ID==1` and so on ..
for that I write this code in MATLAB

```
load calibrage_capteur.mat
data = [ID ,DATE , Valeur]
minid = min(data(:,1));
maxid = max(data(:,1));
for i=minid:maxid

ind=find(data(:,1) == i)
dataID = [ID(ind) ,DATE(ind) , Valeur(ind)]

end
```

As a result he register the last value in this example the max `ID=31` so he register `dataId31`. Now I need how to save the variable each iteration. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use a cell array to hold your data rather than saving them as independent variables that are named based upon the ID.

```
data_by_ID = cell();
ids = minid:maxid;

for k = 1:numel(ids)
    data_by_ID{k} = data(data(:,1) == ids(k),:);
end
```

Really though, depending on what you're doing with it, you can use `data` all of the time since all operations are going to be faster on  a numeric matrix than they are on a cell array.

```
%// Do stuff with data ID = 10
do_stuff(data(data(:,1) == 10, :));
```

**Update**

If you absolutely *must* name your variables you could do the following (but please don't do this and use one of the methods above).

```
for k = 1:numel(ids)
    eval(['dataId', num2str(ids(k)), '= data(k,:);']);
end
```

Comment: Given that op doesn't have a numerical example of what min & max id are, this answer is dangerous/failure prone. For example, if minid is 0, or if minid is some large number.

Comment: thanks but it registred now in a cell array  [309x3 double] [309x3 double] [309x3 double] [309x3 double]

Comment: @yasserbac Yes that is correct. while you *could* save your variables as `dataId31` it is not recommended. Cell arrays are preferred instead.

Comment: @yasserbac I added a brief example at the end of how to do it otherwise, I *highly recommend* that you *not* do it that way though.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear but it sounds like you simply want to save the result at each iteration of the for loop.

I'm assuming min and max id are arbitrary and not necessarily the variable you are trying to index on.

```
    kk = min_id:max_id;
    dataID=nan(size(kk));
    for ii = 1:numel(kk)
       ind=find(data(:,1) == kk(ii))
       dataID(kk) = [ID(ind) ,DATE(ind) , Valeur(ind)]
    end
```

This is better than indexing by min_id or max_id since it isn't clear that min_id starts at at 1 (maybe it starts at 0, or something else.)